# Are there any builds of Unladen Swallow available?

Tags: python, unladen-swallow

I realise there aren't any official ones, but I was hoping I could grab an unofficial one from somewhere?

I'm running 32-bit Windows XP on x86 hardware (Core 2 Duo).

Comment: What was wrong with http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/?

Comment: I'm looking for a pre-built binary, not the source.

Comment: I've not noticed any, when poking around a bit, which makes me wonder how suitable it might be for general usage.

The build instructions for windows don't seem too bad though: http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/wiki/BuildingOnWindows

Comment: Maybe you should try PyPy - another alternative, but this one has a Windows binary:

http://pypy.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, there are no official Windows binaries, so you have to build them on your own.

Download a release from [here](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/), and the instructions for building are here: [BuildingOnWindows](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/wiki/BuildingOnWindows).

A quick Google search suggests that there aren't any others who've followed this procedure and published the results.